# Hide jQuery tab using css

Tags: jquery, css, tabcontrol

Jquery tab control displaying 7 tabs.  When I print the page I only want tab 4 to print.  How can I hide tabs 1-3 and 5-7 of the jQuery tab control in css?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set their display to none as follows:

```
display: none;
```

You'll want to add it to all elements of tabs you want hidden. For example:

```
.hideTabId {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  To be more specific, where would I set this?  In the CSS or in the table itself?

Comment: You should then select the answer as the correct one.... (and a +1 won't hurt anyone)...

Comment: Only one element should have a given id in html.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have the folowing **html**:

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
    <div class="tab">tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 3</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 4</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 5</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 6</div>
    <div class="tab">tab 7</div>
</div>
```

You can do it with **css**:

```
.tab {
  display:none;
}

.tab:nth-child(4) {
    display: block;
}
```

Or **jQuery**

```
$(".tab").hide();
$(".tab:nth-child(4)").show(); // you can also do $(".tab").eq(3).show();
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDzAY/)